# how to change a gnuplot colorbox using custom colors

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot to display the received signal strength of some
small transmitters I'm testing.

The data I'm gathering has the latitude, longitude and RSSI (received 
signal strength indicator).

Sample data:

```
-33.77432033,151.0664296,-49
-33.7743059,151.0665004,-48
-33.77427705,151.0666246,-48
-33.7742775,151.0666962,-47
```

My function to color the values of the signal strength on the map is
as follows:

```
rssicolor(a) = (-a <= 65 ? (255*65536) + ((-a * (255/65))*256) + 0 \
 : (((255-(-a*(255/(120-65))))*65536)) + (255*256) + 0 )
```

For (strong signal) values from (-1 to -65) I plot from red (FF 00 00) to 
yellow (FF FF 00). For (weaker) values from -65 to -120 I plot in colors 
from yellow (FF FF 00) to green (00 FF 00).

So far so good, all these colors are plotted correctly on the map using:

```
plot 'gps-data.txt' using 2:1:(rssicolor($3)) notitle with points lc rgb variable
```

In order to plot data on top of a background I use gnuplot in multiplot mode.

A section of the final resulting image looks like this:

[image: I know, it's not properly aligned]

However, the colorbox on the right of the image shows a vastly different
gradient of colors. It is determined by the function:

```
set cbrange [-40:-120]
set cblabel "Signal Strength (dBm)" offset 0.0,0.0
set zrange [0:1]
unset xlabel 
unset ylabel
unset title
unset xtics
unset ytics
set colorbox vertical user origin 0.87,0.1 size 0.02,0.5
splot '++' u ($1):($2):(cos($1*$2)):($3) with pm3d
unset multiplot
```

I am not sure how I should go about changing (or even interpreting) the command that is responsible for the color scheme in the colorbox.

If I wanted a colorbox with gradient from Red-to-Yellow-to-Green do I 
have to provide a separate data file with colors or can I somehow modify 
the values in the above splot command to get that?

I looked at some of the gnuplot help files but the splot command doesn't 
show a lot of help. Also, studying the examples from the gnuplot website 
shows many different colors being used but they all seem to be picking 
them from a couple of standard color pallettes and I could not see one that goes from red-to-yellow-to-green.

The simplest hack would just be to make my own colorbox in another 
program and cut and paste it over this colorbox.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gnuplot creating palettes is very easy there are tons of ways. Have a look at `help palette`. Among others you have the `defined` mode:

```
set palette defined (0 'red', 1 'yellow', 2 'green')
```

To re-scale to appropriate range, you can use

```
set cbrange [your_min_value : your_max_value]
```

You can have a look at many examples in this [github project](https://github.com/Gnuplotting/gnuplot-palettes)

Comment: I am stumped. This is perfect and so elegant! I immediately used some of my own colors and have it exactly the way I wanted. I did come across the gnuplotting.org website but I was unable to find what I was looking for. The github site correctly demonstrates what is required. Thank you so much! I do have another question regarding background image color distortion but I'll post that in another question and hope you'll be able to shed some light on the matter again.

Comment: what does 0, 1 and 2 mean here? please.. @bibi

Comment: the min and max are arbitrary, but not the ration of the others with respect to them. For exemple 0,1,2 would be equal to 0,0.5,1 or 0,50,100 or -1,0,1 or 0,4,8